# Rails no longer installed after update to xcode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xcode, shell

```
/Users/Louis/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/bin/rails:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /Users/Louis/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rails-4.1.8/bin/rails (LoadError)
from /Users/Louis/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
```

I recently had an update to xcode, and after installing the update I can no longer start a new rails project. When I type :

```
rails new example
```

it displays the error above. How can I fix this?

**EDIT :**

When running :

```
gem install rails
```

the following message came up :

```
The file "/usr/include/iconv.h" is missing in your build environment,
which means you haven't installed Xcode Command Line Tools properly.

To install Command Line Tools, try running `xcode-select --install` on
terminal and follow the instructions.  If it fails, open Xcode.app,
select from the menu "Xcode" - "Open Developer Tool" - "More Developer
Tools" to open the developer site, download the installer for your OS
version and run it.
```

After following the above instructions it seems to have fixed the issue and rails is installing as I type.

Comment: What rails version  are you using?

Comment: It brings up the same error when I type
    rails -v

Comment: `gem install rails`, you can reinstall rails.

Comment: Thanks, i fixed the problem. See above in edit.

Comment: Well，congratulations!